# PHP search and count specific words using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I would like to ask for help with php regex.
i have this code :

```
$search = preg_match_all("/$pattern+/", $file, $matches);
```

for example $pattern will be `"car"` and string to search for `"car acar caracar"`
output should be 3 (1 = car,2 = caracar) but my output is 4

i want to not count a word with prefix like `"acar"` but it will count the pattern with suffix `"caracar"`

thanks for any ideas
i hope its not hard to understand and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use word boundary with `preg_quote`:

```
if ( preg_match_all("/\b" . preg_quote($pattern) . "/", $file, $matches) ) {
    print_r($matches); // or echo count($matches);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but the part with prefix not works :/

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.